# How to avoid PHPExcel re-renders graphs in template?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am exporting info from MySQL to an Excel2007 file.
The script basically reads a template Excel2007 file, adds some data and writes it in a new Excel2007 file.

The template has some graphs within it.
The issue is that they get re rendered and they are slightly different.
(axis titles orientation changed, grpah title orientation changed, scale is changed...)

Is there any way to just add data withoutPHPExcel to interpret and compile the rest of the file?

Thanks!

Gabrie

Answer (score 0):

'fraid not - PHPExcel is not a file editor. The Reader parses the file into the elements that PHPExcel recognises, discarding anything that it doesn't recognise. The Writer takes its elements from the PHPExcel object, unaware that there may have been elements discarded when it was originally loaded.

So it will either discard the chart completely (unless you set includeCharts to TRUE); or it will recreate the chart with some default values for elements or attributes that it doesn't yet handle; in more extreme cases, some features will be lost (secondary axes being a prime example); while in the most extreme it might completely corrupt a chart (but hopefully this should be extremely rare).

- Text orientation isn't yet handled.
- Scale is set purely to default
  (automatic scaling)

In time, more features will be added to charting (handling of stock charts is my next target), but until then it's still limited.

Comment: Thanks Mark ! I undesrtand you are the creator of PHPExcel: Great Job.

Comment: Not actually the creator, but I have been responsible for a lot of the work on it over the last 8 years or so

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the answer in a library: TinyButStrong - http://www.tinybutstrong.com/plugins/opentbs/demo/demo.html

Great for templating! Would be awsome to have them join forces with PHPExcel.

Thanks All for the time spent.